# What is the default value of emitEvent in patchValue method?

Tags: angular

I have checked here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue but I didn't find any informations about what is the default value of `emitEvent`.

```
patchValue(value: {[key: string]: any}, options: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean}): void
```

Does anybody know what this value is?
I would be glad for providing some reliable sources.

Comment: see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L440

Answer (score 2):

Its default value is `false`, because it's `undefined`, but when you use `patchValue`, it also calls `valueChanges` on your form group, so in this logic it is going to be `true` from the point of the method's logic.

Answer (score 0):

`setValue()` and `patchValue()` methods have the same options and the same default values for the options. The default value for both methods is `true`. So they both trigger a `valueChange` event for the control or group of controls being patched. As a result, the control's value will be propagated to the parent form.

Quotation from the documentation:

> `emitEvent`: When true or not supplied (the default), both the statusChanges and valueChanges observables emit events with the latest status and value when the control value is updated. When false, no events are emitted.

Consider this example:

```
this.form.setValue({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
});
```

This will set the values of the "firstName" and "lastName" controls to "John" and "Doe", respectively, and will trigger a valueChange event for those controls.